# Google Sheets: How to search/filter tabs by part of the name

Tags: google-sheets

I have spreadsheet with dozens of sheets with long names. It is very hard to find them in the list-menu etc. Is there a way to filter/find by part of the name?

The only way I found is to click `Alt+/` and search for "Go To Range", and then type `TheRequestedSheetFullName!A1` and jump. The problem is the names contains few words, and it is hard to hit exactly the correct name (I want filtering/searching by part of the name).

Comment: Please see my posted reply. If that fully addresses your posted question/need, please take a moment to mark that reply post as "Best Answer," as this will allow future site visitors like yourself to more easily find this post and information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. In the upper left corner of any sheet (to the far left of the formula bar), there is a field that, by default, shows the current selection in the current sheet. However, if you click in that field and start typing part of a sheet name, a list of all sheets that match will appear. You can then just click on the sheet you want from the shortlist that appears. By default, you will be brought to cell A1 of the sheet you select.

Comment: interesting tip! upvoted

Comment: Thanks, Mike. Personally, I don't think people *should* have dozens of sheets with long names. But my personal feelings aside, this may be a useful tip for others.

Comment: Even if your answer is better, I posted what I do by building a summary.

Comment: Both have their uses, and different people have different preferences. So I don't think of it in terms of "better" or "worse"—just different.

Comment: It's a great tip and helped us a lot. :) Just one thing to notice: it wouldn't find the sheet you are in currently in the list, which is fine, because if you are in it you don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a summary, then search with Ctlr+F

```
function listOfSheetsWithLinks(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var summary = ss.getSheetByName('summary')
  summary.getRange('A:A').clear()
  ss.getSheets().forEach((sh,i) => {
    summary.getRange(+i+1,1).setFormula(`=hyperlink("#gid=${sh.getSheetId()}&range=A1";"${sh.getName()}")`)
  })
}
```